# Instane search delay 1 character

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, regex, post

This is my Ajax script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function searchq() {
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();

    $.post("search1.php", {
        searchVal: searchTxt
    }, function(data) {
        $("#data").html(data);
    });
}
</script>
```

This is my form code

```
<form action="search1.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" onkeydown="searchq()">
</form>
<div id="data"></div>
```

And this is my php code

```
<?
$file  = fopen('aws.csv', 'r');
$output ='';
if (isset($_POST['searchVal'])) {
    $words = $_POST['searchVal'];

    $words = array(preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#"," ",$words));

    $words = array_map('preg_quote', $words);
    // The argument becomes '/wii|guitar/i', which means 'wii or guitar, case-insensitive'
    $regex = '/'.implode('|', $words).'/i';


    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {  
        list($name, $age, $hobbies) = $line;

        if(preg_match($regex, $age)) {
            $output .=  "$name, $age, $hobbies<br/>";
        }

    }
}
echo $regex;
echo $output;
?>
```

My problem is when I enter the value like "Hello" in my search box...
The output of ($regex) will show /Hell/i and not showing /Hello/i ... its delay 1 character...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using `onkeydown`, the event is fired before the key-value is added in the textbox.

Change it to `onkeyup`

```
onkeydown="searchq()"
```

Should be

```
onkeyup="searchq()"
```

[`keyup`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html):

> Fires when the user releases a key, after the default action of that key has been performed.

---

I'll recommend you to use jQuery for event handling instead of inline.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='search']").on('keyup', function() {
        $.post("search1.php", {
            searchVal: $.trim($(this).val()) // Trim: Remove leading & trailing spaces
        }, function(data) {
            $("#data").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: anything else have to change? because the new method that you gave me is not working...

Comment: @user3081581 You've to wrap code in `ready`, check updated code

Comment: @tushar Hi... can you teach me how to make a range search function... for example, I want search from valueA to valueB...